# Pandas: grouping on couples from same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a table (a dataframe) which contains this data:

```
| user     | food          |
|:--------:|:-------------:|
| 'A'      | 'meat'        | 
| 'A'      | 'carrot'      |
| 'A'      | 'candy'       |
| 'B'      |  'meat'       |
| 'B'      |  'carrot'      |
| 'C'      |  'meat'       |
| 'C'      |  'carrot'     |
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user":["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "food":['meat', 'carrot', 'candy', 'meat', 'carrot', 'meat', 'carrot']
})
```

What I'd like to build is a table which for each couple of foods tells me the number of users which have them:

```
| food 1     | food 2        |  num users | 
|:----------:|:-------------:|:----------:| 
| 'meat'     | 'carrot'      | 3          | 
| 'meat'     | 'candy'       | 1          | 
| 'carrot'     | 'candy'       | 1          |
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why 3 for `meat` `carrot`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed, I didn't count right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) first:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('user'), prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0)
print (df)
      candy  carrot  meat
user                     
A         1       1     1
B         0       1     1
C         0       1     1
```

And then count by `list comprehension`:

```
from  itertools import combinations

L = [(x[0], x[1],(df[list(x)] == 1).all(1).sum()) for x in list(combinations(df.columns, 2))]
print (L)
[('candy', 'carrot', 1), ('candy', 'meat', 1), ('carrot', 'meat', 3)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['food 1','food 2','num users'])
print (df)
   food 1  food 2  num users
0   candy  carrot          1
1   candy    meat          1
2  carrot    meat          3
```

Comment: Thanks, it's quite slow on large dataframes but good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
food_pairs = [("meat", "carrot"), ("meat", "candy")]

food_to_users = {food: set(df.user[df.food == food].unique()) for food in df.food.unique()}

out = pd.DataFrame(
    ((*pair, len(set.intersection(*(food_to_users[food] for food in pair)))) for pair in food_pairs),
    columns=["food1", "food2", "num users"]
)
```

Average run time over 1000 trials was `0.00256s`.

Test code for scalability:

```
import itertools
import math
import pandas as pd
from random import shuffle
from timeit import time

SIZE_OF_PAIRS = 2
NUM_FOODS = 50
NUM_USERS = 1000
NUM_RECORDS = 100000

foods = (list(range(NUM_FOODS)) * (math.ceil(NUM_RECORDS/NUM_FOODS)))[:NUM_RECORDS]
users = (list(range(NUM_USERS)) * (math.ceil(NUM_RECORDS/NUM_USERS)))[:NUM_RECORDS]

shuffle(foods)
shuffle(users)

df = pd.DataFrame({"user": users, "food": foods})

food_pairs = pd.Series([*itertools.combinations(df.food.unique(), SIZE_OF_PAIRS)])

start = time.time()

food_to_users = {food: set(df.user[df.food == food].unique()) for food in df.food.unique()}
out = pd.DataFrame(
    ((*pair, len(set.intersection(*(food_to_users[food] for food in pair)))) for pair in food_pairs),
    columns=[*["food" + str(i) for i in range(SIZE_OF_PAIRS)], "num users"]
)

print("Time taken: {}s".format(time.time() - start))
```

Comment: Is the measured time done on the sample dataframe I gave?

Comment: @martin Yeah, excluding `food_pairs` creation.

Comment: Would it scale reasonably with much larger dataframes?

Comment: @martin I've not done any thorough analysis of the complexity or if there are more efficient methods but I've edited the answer to include a test code that you can modify the parameters to see if the performance is acceptable.

Comment: @martin Also by the way, it runs about 20 times faster if your data types are int's instead of string's. Haven't looked into why this is but yeah something to consider.